# Why a "static" array doesn't work with GitHub contains workflow expression?

Tags: github, github-actions

[From the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#contains), this works:

```
contains('Hello world', 'llo')
```

However, this will not:

```
contains(['6', '7', '8'], matrix.foo)
```

> Unexpected symbol: '['. Located at position 10 within expression: contains(['6', '7', '8'], matrix.foo)

Is there any way to check the that `matrix.fo`o is either 6, 7, or 8 using `contains`?

Comment: Any more context? Is it used in an if condition? The ad-hoc solution might be transforming to string, although your approach is way more sensible.

Answer (score 1):

The [contains](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#contains) function can't achieve the result you expect alone, you would also need to use the [fromJson](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#fromjson) function with an array list.

In that case, your expression should instead look like this:

```
if: contains(fromJson('["6", "7", "8"]'), matrix.foo)
```

and the opposite like this:

```
if: ${{ !contains(fromJson('["6", "7", "8"]'), matrix.foo) }}
```

---

I tested it here if you want to have a look:

- [workflow file](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester33.yml)
- [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/2371173099)

Comment: Thanks so much for the input! It was not clear from the documentation, i've read it a lot of times :)